# Android Contacts content provider not getting updated when a contact is added in background

Tags: android, contacts

I'm developing an application that displays a list of contacts by fetching them from the Android contacts content provider.
In the `onResume` method of my fragment I restart a `Loader` that fetches the contacts from the Contacts content provider and it works fine.
However if I background the app, then use the default Android contacts app to add a contact and then bring my app to background I don't see the new contact added to the list even though `onResume` is called and the loader is being restarted.

I've debugged my code and it just seems that the new contact is simply not being returned from the Contacts content provider.
If I terminate the app (swipe it from the recent menu) and re-open it, then I'll see the new contact in the list.

Do you know what the issue could be?

Thanks,
Ido

Comment: hmm, why was my question down-voted?
It seems like a legitimate question and I couldn't find any duplicates for it.